# React Native, Android - This item may not have a label readable by screen readers

Tags: react-native, google-play

I have this message on google play console for pre-launch release:

```
This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.
```

And this is the image they provided:

[image]

I don't understand what this means can someone help? i have another few issues with the app for accessibility reasons

Comment: Can you post the code please. Usually this means you should set the accessibilityLabel on the component